# How to enable kubernetes dashboard via nodeport?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

I'm trying to enable dashboard via nodeport service.
I have 3 VMs:

- 192.168.100.31 - master
- 192.168.100.32 - minion
- 192.168.100.33 - minion (dashboard here)

After applying:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

Dashboard became accessable via kube-proxy. So I've erited service to become NodePort:

```
kubectl edit services kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system
```

Then I've tried to access the dashboard via https NodePort. And it fails. When I'm trying to visit 192.168.100.31 or 192.168.100.32 like:

```
https://192.168.100.31:32443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/#!/overview?namespace=default
```

Browser hangs out & fired timeout error.
Meanwhile the same URL for 192.168.100.33 allow me to add site to the browser exceptions cause of self signed cert and ... fail.

```
This site can’t be reached
The webpage at https://192.168.100.33:32443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/#!/overview?namespace=default might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE
```

kubernetes version: v1.11.1

**UPD:**

kubectl get svc kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system --export -o yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"creationTimestamp":null,"labels":{"k8s-app":"kubernetes-dashboard"},"name":"kubernetes-dashboard","namespace":"kube-system","selfLink":"/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard"},"spec":{"ports":[{"nodePort":32443,"port":443,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":8443}],"selector":{"k8s-app":"kubernetes-dashboard"},"sessionAffinity":"None","type":"NodePort"},"status":{"loadBalancer":{}}}
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

kubectl get svc kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system

```
NAME                   TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
kubernetes-dashboard   NodePort   10.96.174.242   <none>        443:32443/TCP   52m
```

kubectl describe svc kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system

```
Name:                     kubernetes-dashboard
Namespace:                kube-system
Labels:                   k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"creationTimestamp":null,"labels":{"k8s-app":"kubernetes-dashboard"},"name":"kubernete...
Selector:                 k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.96.174.242
Port:                     <unset>  443/TCP
TargetPort:               8443/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  32443/TCP
Endpoints:                192.0.2.2:8443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Comment: can you check which port is being used with the command `kubectl -n kube-system get service kubernetes-dashboard`?

Comment: Could you add to your question output of the command: < kubectl get svc kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system --export -o yaml > and < kubectl get svc kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system > and < kubectl describe svc kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system >

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same issue as you. Is this a bug? Seems odd that exactly the same issue is surfacing and I can't find it anywhere else on the web (got here from a relatively fruitless google search)

Comment: @SamHolmes my initial goal was to enable dashboard access for extraneous machines. So for now I've switched to token base access via API server. Found this article useful: www.joseluisgomez.com/containers/kubernetes-dashboard/

Comment: Whoa what a great article, thank you @Silk0vsky!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are using an `apiserver` type of request while accessing  the `dashboard` service directly via NodePort Service.

Could you check the following links in your browser to access Kubernetes dashboard:

https://192.168.100.31:32433/

https://192.168.100.32:32433/

https://192.168.100.33:32433/

Answer (score 0):

youre pod types is "**NodePort**". fine!.

finde your node ip (Master ip)

for example type:

```
ip a
```

and ...

```
curl -k http://<Node IP>:32443
```

Enjoy It!